# How to create an error message when input value is Float type and not Integer type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling, floating-point, integer

For a school assignment i have been given the task of creating a function that determines whether a year is a leap year or not.

Below is what i have so far. e.g When i type, "days_in_Year 2018" it returns "Non-Leap Year". This function only works for Integer value inputs. I need some extra code that will return an error message when the input value is a double or float value.

```
days_in_Year :: Integer -> String
days_in_Year year
 | year `mod` 400 == 0 = "Leap Year"
 | year `mod` 100 == 0 = "Non-Leap Year"
 | year `mod` 4 == 0   = "Leap Year"
 | otherwise = "Non-Leap Year"
```

I would like my function to be able to return "Invalid Input" when a double or float value is the input...

Comment: Your input verification needs to go where you do your input, which you haven't shown us. It can't go in this function; that's way too late!

Comment: You specified an `Integer` input in the type annotation, so if you try to pass anything else, the compiler will already give you an error about it being invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the major advantages of Haskell is that the type-system enforces the distinction of "pure" functions from "impure" functions. What you've got there is a pure function - you promise to give it an `Integer`, and the function promises to always give you a good result (no error). (These promises are contractually enforced by the compiler ie. at compile-time, because Haskell is a statically-typed language.) This makes code much easier to reason about. Whilst you do need to deal with what happens if the users input is badly behaved, and could modify the function (and it's type signature) to do so, it's good practice to put that code elsewhere - like where you parse the input from the user.

Which begs the question, how are you getting user input such that it might be a `Integer` or a `Float` or a `Double`? A simple pattern would be something like eg.

```
import Text.Read

main = do
    s <- getLine
    case readMaybe s of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Please enter an integer"
        Just x -> putStrLn $ days_in_Year x
```

Here, because `x` is provided as an argument to `days_in_Year`, the compiler knows that you're trying to read the string `s` as an `Integer`, and if it can't (eg. because `s == "5.0"`), then it will just return `Nothing` and you can tell the user what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! I apologise but im new to haskell and i am not too sure how i would implement this directly into my code... would you perhaps be able to show me?

Comment: @LaurensMellink I edited it, should have been `getLine` not `readLn` sorry.

Comment: While the function is, in fact, pure, that's not really important here. The point is that Haskell is statically typed, which means the *compiler* will catch any attempt to pass a non-`Integer` value as the argument to `days_in_Year`, rather than the function having to detect the type of the value passed to it at run time.

Comment: @chepner I think it is important here. You're saying having fixed the functions type, the compiler catches any attempts to pass a bad argument type therefore the error happens at compile-time. I'm making the subjective point that the runtime error of detecting a bad input belongs in a different function (though you could modify the function to accept a string and do error handling here, one should not do so! And thus function should remain pure).

Comment: @chepner Perhaps I was confusing the two somewhat, edited for clarity.

Comment: Also, the purity comes from not just the type, but the fact that the case analysis is exhaustive: the compiler guarantees that only an `Integer` can be passed, but the function definition is what ensures that each of those `Integer` values gets mapped to a `String`. `readMaybe` is also pure (unlike `read`), because we've augmented the codomain from `Integer` to `Maybe Integer` to allow for those `String` values that can't be mapped to an `Integer` value.

Comment: @chepner Is that really so different to saying "because you can use `error` anywhere then really you always have to inspect the implementation to determine a function's purity"? Re. the second point, I've been thinking about what "purity" actually means. I could argue `read` is just as pure as `readMaybe`; both are referentially transparent, but as you've observed type doesn't actually prevent arbitrary errors (eg. `readMaybe` could run out of memory).

Comment: @chepner Is `f :: IO a` pure? I think you could argue yes and no from different perspectives depending on the level at which you evaluate purity. But you do want to be able to colloquially say it's "less pure" than `f :: a`. Similarly for `f :: String -> Maybe b" vs `f' :: a -> b` with the parsing done outside `f'`; I think `f'` is "purer" even when parsing is done "purely" inside `f` with a `readMaybe`, and hence even `Maybe` is indicating some level of "impurity".

Comment: You have to have a function before you can discuss purity, and `f :: IO a` is not a function. I don't know what you mean with comparisons of monomorphic to polymorphic types; it doesn't really have anything to do with purity. You don't have the option of writing an impure total function in Haskell, unless you do something ill-advised like use `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190967/discussion-between-a-tayler-and-chepner).